# SQL Pulling data from nearest date for multiple months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data of date and color in a mysql database

```
2023-01-28 red
2023-01-29 blue
2023-01-30 blue
2023-01-31 red
2023-02-01 blue
2023-02-02 blue
2023-02-03 blue
2023-02-04 blue
2023-02-05 red
```

How can I pull the closest date to current date from each month and the associated color? Example answer for above code would be

```
2023-01-31 red
2023-02-05 red
```

Comment: What database system: MS SQL, MySQL, PostgrSql, other?

Comment: Database system is MYSQL

Comment: I'd use [MAX function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: 'closest date to current date from each month' - looks more like last per month , but what if there are more than 1 colour that matches this rule?

Comment: @P.Salmon There will only be one color for each date. And last per month wont always work as the database is only populated up to the current date.

Comment: Not with you , do you mean some months might not be populated at all?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have MySQL, therefore, I am going to use SQL Fiddle.

```
-- 1 - Create table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS colors 
(
    the_date DATE,
    the_color VARCHAR(16)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

-- 2 - Add data
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-01-28', 'red');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-01-29', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-01-30', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-01-31', 'red');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-02-01', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-02-02', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-02-03', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-02-04', 'blue');
INSERT INTO colors VALUES ('2023-02-05', 'red');
```

Steps 1 & 2 create the table and add the data.  Step 3 will want to covert the date into YYYYMM format for grouping and aggregation.  Then group by that new fields and the color, selecting the date that is the largest using the MAX() function.

I could have left the new column in the final results, but you did not have it in the result set.  Therefore, use a derived table to get the result in the () inner statement and select the two fields (columns) you want in the outer statement.

```
-- 3 - Solve the problem
SELECT
  the_color,
  the_largest_dte
FROM
(
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(the_date, '%Y%m') as the_yyyy_mm,
  the_color,
  max(the_date) as the_largest_dte
FROM colors
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(the_date, '%Y%m'),
  the_color
) AS D
```

The screen shot below shows everything together.

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1700b5/7/0

Comment: This solution looks good, but does it meet OP's criteria?

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, you have to use [MAX function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html).

I'm not sure i understand your requirements, but i think you want to get all instance of color which date is the newest...

```
WITH MD AS
(
  SELECT MAX(datefld) as maxdate
  FROM mytable
),
CR AS
(
  SELECT datefld, colorfld
  FROM mytable AS MT
  INNER JOIN MD
    ON MT.datefld = MD.maxdate
)
SELECT MT.*
FROM CR
INNER JOIN mytable AS MT
  ON MT.colorfld = CR.colorfld
    AND MT.datefld <= CR.datefld
ORDER BY MT.datefld;
```

[SQLFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gN0hWnVY)

Result:

| datefld | colorfld |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-28 00:00:00 | red |
| 2023-01-31 00:00:00 | red |
| 2023-02-05 00:00:00 | red |

Comment: Using max function and grouping by month and year of date ended up working for me

Answer (score 0):

I got your desired output.

```
with td as (select *,datediff(CURRENT_DATE(),tdate) ds from temp_data)
select tdate,color from td where ds in
  (
with tp as(
select month(tdate), min(datediff(CURRENT_DATE(),tdate)) as days from temp_data group by month(tdate))
select days from tp)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/92RoM59i